# Move /home on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos

I need to move my /home to /dev/md3 because I need more disk space for it, but I don't know how to do that. I copied the contents of "/home" to "/var/home", but I do not know how to assign "/var/home" as default.

`~]# df
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20186312 16210740    2951628  85% /
devtmpfs         32968360        0   32968360   0% /dev
tmpfs            33001816      564   33001252   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            33001816   372704   32629112   2% /run
tmpfs            33001816        0   33001816   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3       1902052420 15295092 1790115644   1% /var`

`~]# cat /etc/fstab
file          system   mount        point      type  options       dump  pass
/dev/md2        /       ext3    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md3        /var    ext4    defaults,usrquota,grpquota      1       2
/dev/sda4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0`

I would greatly appreciate your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [do it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-default-home-directory/) by changing:

- Default home directory - `HOME` variable in `/etc/default/useradd`.
- Current users home directories - `usermod -m -d /path/to/new/home/dir userNameHere`.

But IMO splitting /dev/md3 on partitions and making one of them a `home` is a better solution.

*Edited: TD.512 suggestion, formating.*

Comment: can we get a basic description of what to do? Posting only links are useless, as they could disappear at any point in time.